# Invoice numbers scrambled in WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce

Hi i've installed the plugin " WooCommerce Print Invoice & Delivery Note "

I have nearly 800 invoices to print, though when I'm entering 401+ invoices every invoice number gets scrambled.

Ex.

Invoice number should be 402 but is instead 5,
That increments for like 75 invoices and then starts at 1 again again.

Any suggestions on what to do?

Comment: Have you contacted the plugin author?

Comment: No I haven't, could he help?

Comment: If it is a premium plugin not many people on here will have access to it anyway. So if the problem you have concerns that plugin specifically, it seems like a good start.

Comment: It's a free plugin - and there's no premium features.

Comment: [Plugin specific forum](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/woocommerce-delivery-notes). I'd try there first anyway.

Comment: No other suggestions?